# Stop Facebook Share Dialog bunching links from the same domain

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Share Dialog with the latest Javascript API version 2.1.  The shared links appear in my Facebook timeline fine - but if multiple 'shares' are made then Facebook seems to group or bunch them together.

[image]

I guess it is doing this as they are from the same domain or from the same Facebook APP ID.  Anyone know how to prevent this bunching behaviour?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't control that behavior.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  Looks like we'll have to live with it.